# Post call for xml content using HttpClient

Tags: c#, xml, httpclient

How to make xml content compatible with `HttpClient's` `PostAsync` operation for the content and where do you specify the `headers` for `Content-Type = application/xml`.

**Error** -> Cannot convert string to `HttpContent`

```
public async Task GetCustomersAsync(string firstname, string lastname)
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi...";

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://domain.com/scripts/WebObj.exe/Client.woa/2/ws/ABC", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is what you want to do is the following:

```
public async Task<string> GetCustomersAsync(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi...", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");;

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/scripts/WebObj.exe/Client.woa/2/ws/ABC", content);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

OR

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequesteUri = new Uri("POST_URL"), Method = HttpMethod.Post })
{
    var content = new StringContent("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi...");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
}
```

You can [refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) to more information about other Content types that can be created and passed.

Comment: thanks, how and were do you specify headers, for instance `content-type` in this case

Comment: @user2727195 I've updated my answer. That header is for the contenttype specifically, in the first example, the last parameter to the constructor is set as the Content-Type header. If you are looking for different headers though, that is done on the request object itself request.Headers.Add("HEADER_KEY", "HEADER_VALUE")

Comment: I see, the httpclient reads from the content, encoding and it's content-type and sets the headers accordingly, right?\

Comment: Correct(at least as far as I understand it).

Comment: Can you please add a line to call this method and output the result string from outside this method, for instance `foo.GetCustomersAsync("", "").ContinueWith...`, I'm new to this

Comment: @user2727195 Updated: I believe this is what you were asking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes 90%, I like the first version, the rest 10% is how to call this function and output the result string, for instance if class is `Foo` and object is `foo`, how do I call and output the result string, for instance `foo.GetCustomersAsync("", "").ContinueWith`???

Comment: I'm having some issues the call is not returning, how can I diagnose, any error handlers I can use to figure out the error, right now it's a silent fail.

Answer (score 2):

To specifically request xml content in response you must define the content type in the header of the content.  The MediaTypeHeaderValue is parsed and set in the ContentType property of the content Headers.  Here is a complete example of the code;

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(messageToPOST, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml");
    response = await client.PostAsync(_uri, content);
    responseMsg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The responseMsg property returned by the request as the response can be parsed as a string and otherwise converted to and validated as xml using an expression such as

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(responseMsg);
string xmlAsString = xdoc.ToString();
```